# How to run the tests of a module along with my application tests

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

What I am trying to achieve is to run the tests written in my modules along the with tests of the application. When we run `gradlew test` it runs all the tests of my app and modules, but my app has a lot of flavors and it's really impractical to run tests for all the flavors before building for a specific flavor.

So, I want to be able to run command `gradlew TestQADebug` and be able to run the tests in my modules along with the tests for the QA flavored debug build.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `gradlew -q <task-name> <task-name>`.

In your case, try below:
`gradlew -q moduleName:testDebugUnitTest app:testQADebugUnitTest`

More info there --> http://www.ekiras.com/2016/12/how-to-run-single-or-multiple-gradle-tasks.html